# Findout address of shellcode dynamically, placed on stack

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow, c, shellcode

I am using shellcode to spawn a shell,I am curious to findout the starting address of shellcode dynamically,which is placed on stack and not hard code the address in the shellcode
kindly share your ideas ?
I have gone through [Smashing stack for fun and profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html) ,however i was curious to know how CODERED worm or MORRIS WORM figures out the address of shellcode dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can find gadgets to do that for you.

If you find a set of gadgets which will result in one of the registers containing the starting address of the shellcode, you just need a 'jmp eax'(assuming the address is in eax) which will execute your shellcode.

You'll have to overwrite the saved eip to the address of your first gadget though.

Hope this helped